# Ember.js Observer don't work on sub array, what is my mistake?

Tags: ember.js

in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/stephane_klein/yU6PZ/4/

why observer isn't executed when I do ?

```
monday.pushObject(App.Event.create({ title: 'event 1' }));
```

What "path" I need to put in my observer to fix it ?

Best regards,
Stephane

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug in Ember, https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/541, regarding this problem. Currently, this bug seems to prevent nested array observers.